# JQuery .on('change') and displaying data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that is dynamically generated. When the user makes a change to an input, the changes are displayed on the right hemisphere of the screen. I can directly call a variable that is set to that change, but when I loop through all of the sibling inputs to get the current data, they are the default values. How can I fix this?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NEEtV/2/

```
$('#question-data form input').on('change',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('#test-preview').empty();
    $(this).parents('form').find('input').each(function(){
        $('#test-preview').append('<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>');
    })
});
```

you'll see in console that $(this).val() is current, but not on the display side of the screen.

Comment: *"I can directly call a variable"* You don't "call" variables. You can refer to them, display them, read their values, update them, but you don't call them. You call functions.

Comment: That fiddle is **way** too complicated. Create a [**minimal**, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) (and post it to your question in its entirety) when asking for help. Two reasons: 1. In the process, you're likely to figure out what's going wrong. 2. If you don't, you have something reasonably contained that people can work with.

Comment: you are referring to the value of the Input field witch has not been updated in the DOM.

Comment: @MilchePatern: Not if they're using `.val()`, they aren't.

Comment: On `$('#test-preview').append('<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>');` the `$(this)` is now referencing to `$(this).parents('form').find('input')`, not to original `$('#question-data form input')`. To work, use `$('#test-preview').append('<p>' + x + '</p>');`. Of course, based on the code you posted on question. The fiddle is too big, as T.J. said.

Comment: creating a simpler fiddle, give me a few minutes

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For some reason, the DOM population is not sync to the document rendering. There is a trigger in between. Like per IE, it's when the form field LOOSES focus. For other browser it's on onBlur, etc etc. And i just suspected the OP was trying to access a not-updated data in html element, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the following modifications

```
$('#question-form').on('change', '.add-question input, textarea',function() {
    $('#test-preview').children('div').empty();
    var i = 1;
    $('#question-form').find('.add-question').each(function() {
        $('#test-preview').children('div').append('<p>Question ' + i);
        $(this).find('input,textarea').each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'description' || $(this).attr('id') == 'points'){
                $('#test-preview').children('div').append($(this).val() + '<br />');
            }
        });
        $('#test-preview').children('div').append('</p>');
        i++;
    });
});
```

basically it was the way I was selecting the value of $(this)